# directive with inline tpl containing ng-include

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, angularjs-http

I have a directive with inline template containing a ng-include directive element.

When karma testing my directive and logging the result of compiled element . the tesult contains a ng comment saying the ng-include is undefined . What do I make wrong ? The directive works fine but the karma testing seems not work.

Answer (score 2):

I think I know what you're asking but the question can really use some revision, and include some sample code. I'm going attempt to answer because I ran into this issue a while back and it took a lot of hair pulling to finally figure it out and the fix is really easy.

I'm have to make a few assumptions and expand on this question to clarify the scenario for future readers.

Assumption 1: your directive works in normal use outside of testing.

Assumption 2: the root element of your directive template is the one with `ng-include`. Basically, it looks like this:

```
module('myapp').directive('myDirective', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      template: '<ng-include src="myRealTemplateUrl" ></div>',
    }
});
```

Assumption 3: When you create and run a Jasmine unit-test similar to this one, the result of `elem.html()` is undefined:

```
it('Renders something cool">', function(){
    var elem = $compile('<my-directive></my-directive>')($scope);
    $scope.$digest();

    console.log('ELEM', elem.html());

    expect(elem.html()).toContain("foo);
});
```

With that out of the way, this question now can be answered.

`ng-include` uses element transclusion. When the root node of the HTML fragment passed to `$compile` uses element transclusion, Angular turns that root node into a comment node. Angular then appends the rendered version of your directive as a sibling node right below that original root node. So `elem` is now a comment node, and therefore `elem.html()` is `undefined`.

More thorough explanations can be seen in [this tutorial](http://taivo.github.io/guides/unit-testing-angular-directives) or [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing#testing-transclusion-directives)

The solution is simple though, just wrap whatever you passed to `$compile` inside another root element. So don't do this:

```
// don't do this
var elem = $compile('<my-directive></my-directive>')($scope);
```

do this:

```
// but do this
var elem = $compile('<div><my-directive></my-directive></div>')($scope);
```

That's all you have to do to make top-level `ng-include` work in a unit test.